# How to load hugging face base model from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: pytorch, google-cloud-storage, huggingface-transformers, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I would like to load a hugging face base model (xlm-roberta-base) from Google Cloud Storage without downloading to my local directory if possible. My model is a PyTorch model which builds on the hugging face base model. How can I go about this?

I can download blobs with a particular prefix from my bucket, but I would like to do it without actually persisting the downloaded blobs in my local directory.

Comment: I'm interested in that too. Have you found something?